# Postman Pre-Request Script to Read Variables from CSV file and Append to JSON Body

Tags: javascript, python, csv, postman, jq

I have a JSON body with template to pass to an API endpoint in Postman/Newman as follows:

```
{
  "total": [
    {
      "var1a": "ABCDE",
      "var1b": {
        "var2a": "http://url/site/{{yyyy}}/{{mmdd}}/{{yyyymmdd}}.zip",
        "var2b": {
           "var3a": "{{yyyymmdd}}",
           "var3b": "GKG"
        },
        "var2c": "ABCDE"
        "var2d": "{{p}}"
      }
    },
    {
      "var1a": "ABCDE",
      "var1b": {
        "var2a": "http://url/site/{{yyyy}}/{{mmdd}}/{{yyyymmdd}}.zip",
        "var2b": {
           "var3a": "{{yyyymmdd}}",
           "var3b": "GKG"
        },
        "var2c": "ABCDE"
        "var2d": "{{p}}"
      }
    }
}
```

Everything enclosed in double braces is a variable that needs to read from an external CSV file, which looks like:

```
p,yyyymmdd,yyyy,mmdd
1,19991231,1999,1231
2,20001230,2000,1230
```

- Note that the CSV isn't necessarily 2 entries long - I'd ideally like it to take in a dynamic number of entries that append after the last.
- Ideally, I'd get rid of the last two columns in the CSV file (`yyyy` and `mmdd`) and have the code just do a slice as needed.

How do I even begin coding the pre-request script?

Even if reading from an external CSV is not possible, or even coding within the pre-request script to do this, what is a quick one-liner in Javascript or Python that can quickly give me the output I need so that I can just manually place it in the request body?

I even tried using the Postman runner to do a "fake" run so that I can quickly extract the different JSON bodies, but even with this, there is no clean way that it does the export...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading data from CSV is not the good way to solve problem because each record is will be used to one request. You want the whole record into ONE request.

I think write code in pre-request script will work.

In body tab:

[image]

In pre-rquest tab:

```
let data_set = [
    [1, 1999, 1231],
    [2, 2000, 1230]
];

let total = [];

for (let i = 0; i < data_set.length; i++) {
    let p = data_set[i][0];
    let yyyy = data_set[i][1];
    let mmdd = data_set[i][2];

    const item = {
        var1a: "ABCDE",
        var1b: {
            var2a: `http://url/site/${yyyy}/${mmdd}/${yyyy}${mmdd}.zip`,
            var2b: {
                var3a: `${yyyy}${mmdd}`,
                var3b: "GKG"
            },
            var2c: "ABCDE",
            var2d: `${p}`
        }
    };

    total.push(item);
}

pm.environment.set("total", JSON.stringify(total));
```